# What would be the best search engine design for multi language search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a database in which I store over 3 million documents with titles in different languages.
Each document has the following (simplified) structure:

```
{name: "The Intouchables",
  detail: {
    original_title: "Intouchables"
    spanish_title: "Intocable"
  }
}
```

My users search either in Spanish or English. Text index feature in Mongodb enables you to specify the **language for each document** and a **default language**. Having this into account, how would you **design a great search engine** that:

- Searches fast (I would like to incorporate autocompletion soon) for titles
- Is accurate
- User can search in English or Spanish

For the time being, I would like to adjust to what Mongodb brings to the table, but I'm open to other technologies if they really change the game (Redis, Elasticsearch, etc.)

Some work I've already done:

I have indexed all my documents with default_language "none". That's inefficient due to the great amount of potential stop words that are stored. If I set default_language as English or Spanish, results are not accurate due to stop-word matching (it gives irrelevant results: for example, giving good score for titles with word "The"...a lot).

Some ideas:

- Using [mongoid_search](https://github.com/mauriciozaffari/mongoid_search) (keywords based on specified fields) and make `_keywords` field text indexed.
- Specify language override for titles in spanish. Make both English and Spanish search (two queries) and intersect results (not big fan).

Comment: I would suggest using a purpose-built text search engine like elasticsearch for this. MongoDB's text search probably shouldn't be the reason you use MongoDB, since it's not the main purpose of the software. It's more like a nice bonus for a lot of use cases.

Comment: @wdberkeley: Thanks. The reason why I'm using Mongodb is not because its text search functionality. However, if I don't have to use any other technology, that would be great. **According to the specs** I posted, where do you see Elasticsearch will make a difference?